# R: median in bins for 3D data

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors of the same size x, y, and z.
I want to project x and y into a 2D grid, i.e, splitting the (x,y) point into bins. For all the points in each bin I want to compute the median of the corresponding z values. Is there a compact way to do it in R? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use `tapply()` to apply a function based on multiple indices:

```
tapply(y, INDEX=list(x, y), FUN=median)   ## you can add na.rm=TRUE at the end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Before using tapply() I have to assign each point to its 2D bin, how can I do it? I would need a function like table() but giving not the number of objects per bin but the full list or the median

Comment: If `x` and `y` are continuous variables that can take many values, then you can form discrete variables (say `x.bin` and `y.bin`) using the `cut()` function. You need to think about how you want the bins defined, and feed a vector of breaks into this function.